# Jquery - Mass linking buttons to associated div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, modal-dialog

I have created a simple jquery popup.
Throughout my site I have several btns that each link to a different pop up.

**My question:**
Is there a way to link all buttons to there relevant popups without having to list every button and div by name as I begun to do so below?
Or alternatively the shortest way to list all buttons and divs without having to write the click event for each?

```
$(function() {
  $('.Btn1').click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();
  $('.Pop1').fadeIn();});
  $('.Btn2').click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();
  $('.Pop2').fadeIn();});
  var modalBgd = $('.PopBgd')
  $('.PopClose, .PopBgd').click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();
  modalBgd.fadeOut();});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could provide the id/class of the popup within a data element in the link like this:

```
<a href="#" data-popup=".Pop1" class="openpopup">open popup 1</a>
<a href="#" data-popup=".Pop2" class="openpopup">open popup 2</a>
```

that'll reduce your javascript to this:

```
$('.openpopup').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $($(this).data('popup')).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: This is awesome it does everything I need so elegantly. There's something about small code that makes me all gooey inside.
Nadine you are a genius and I am indebted.
Definitely the best answer to my particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how your links/button/clickable elements look like. I would do something like this: select all of these elements and just apply the event handler to them e.g.

```
$(".popup").click(...);
```

You can use a more sophisticated selector to it but the idea is always the same. Remember that a element can have multiple classes to it.